# Rails carrierwave+Jcrop crop picture with Bootstrap Modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.8'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.2'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'
gem 'Jcrop', '~> 0.1.0'
```

and then I write the code as it 
`https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/cropping-images-with-jcrop`

It works good.

But the problem is when I want to change the `crop.html.erb` to use `Bootstrap`  `_modal.html.erb`, How should change the `user_controller.erb`?

the original codes is like this :

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      if params[:user][:picture].present?
        render :crop   ###this how to change use modal.html
      else
        redirect_to @user
        flash[:success] = "更新成功"
      end
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

I had try as

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819575/how-to-show-modal-window-in-controllers-action?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa
```

And the new `user_controller.erb`

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      if params[:user][:picture].present?
        respond_to do |format|  ##change here
          format.js    ##change here
        end   ##change here
      else
        redirect_to @user
        flash[:success] = "更新成功"
      end
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

But it always show that :

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

If add `format.html` ,it has wrongs `templates missing`, because I write the html codes in `show.html.erb`,it likes:

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <div class="row " id="user_avatar_crop">
    <!-- Choose picture -->
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%= f.file_field :picture, id: :user_avatar, :onchange => 'this.form.submit()' %>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->
<% end %>
<div class="userAvatarUpload">

</div>
<%= image_tag @user.picture_url(:thumb) if @user.picture? %>
```

How should I `format.html` to `show.html.erb` ?

My questions just like this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027034/rails-carrierwave-jcrop-bootstrap
```

Should I just had to use paperclip like him?  Is there any method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
if params[:user][:picture].present?
    render :crop   ###this how to change use modal.html
  else
```

Whenever you use `render`, you're rendering an action, not an HTML page. My advice would be to just create a new action with the name `bootstrap _modal` (do not use Bootstrap with a capital B) and rename your `Bootstrap _modal.html.erb` to `bootstrap _modal.html.erb`.

Comment: Thanks @a3y3. I want to pop the `modal` in current page, if I render to an action , will it  jump to a new page? And the `modal` display should use JS `$('#xxx').modal("show")`,how could `controller`   `render` to call the JS file?

Comment: Hi @a3y3,in this question , the second answer by `@Zelenka` seems can achieve the result, but how could set the  variable, can you give me some suggests?  The question link:`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819575/how-to-show-modal-window-in-controllers-action`